# Profiling Dask Distributed Communication between workers and client

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I would like to ask whether there is a way to measure the communication in time between workers and a client. Currently, I am using a Scheduler plugin to get the task states and get details for the execution from there. I do not see though any transfer tasks when the results are returned to the client. Is it fair to assume that it is equal to the time between the last finished task and when compute returned?

How can we also find the amount of data moved from each task to the client?

A general example would be

```
{task: id, "Bytes Returned": 128, "Time":50ms}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to use Scheduler plugin?

Comment: You can find one [here](https://github.com/radical-cybertools/midas/blob/master/Dask/schedulerPlugin.py)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no mechanism that measures communications to and from the client.